# Maya Python select each time next listed object

Tags: python, maya

I am looking for a way to select each time a different object contained in a list,
so if my list contains [pCube1, pCube2, pCube3]. The first time it select the first element (pCube1), than the second (pCube2) ecc. Do you think is possible with Python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you just tried a for loop?

```
l = [pCube1, pCube2, pCube3]
n = len(l) - 1

for i in range(0, n):
    current_element = l[i]
    do_something(current_element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for an iterator

```py
x = iter([1,2,3])
next(x) # 1
next(x) # 2
next(x) # 3
next(x) # will throw an exception
```